# Ansible: Generate a random string and share it between all hosts

Tags: random, ansible

I want a task that will generate a random string or timestamp and send that to all hosts in the play.

For example, if I do this:

```
- name: Create a unique ID
  shell: random_string
  register: unique_id

- name: store the unique ID
  lineinfile:
    dest: '/home/project/config.txt'
    regexp: 'unique_id'
    line: 'unique_id = "{{ unique_id }}'
```

This will generate the random string separately on each remote machine, so they won't match. I could generate it on the local machine using local_action, but it still would run separately for each host. So how can I ensure it will be the same for all hosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`run_once`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) in combination with [`delegate_to`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) or `local_action` to get it to generate your variable just once.

So your first task would just look like this:

```
- name: Create a unique ID
  shell: random_string
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  register: unique_id
```

Comment: run_once is what I needed. Thanks